# Append each line from a text file to a list

Tags: python, file-io

My problem is that I want to append each line of a file to a list.
Here's what it looks like on the text file:

```
-1,2,1
0,4,4,1
```

I want to append the contents of each line into a list of it's own:

```
list1 = [-1, 2, 1]
list2 = [0, 4, 4, 1]
```

Comment: A list of lists is going to be much more convenient than hundreds of separate variables.  For one thing, it's much easier to iterate over them.

Comment: i don't know how to read text files.  Up to this point, I have only been using inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
list_dict = {} # create dict to store all the lists

with open(infile) as f: # use with to open your file as it closes them automatically
   for ind,line in enumerate(f,1): # use enumerate to keep track of each line index 
       list_dict["list{}".format(ind)] = map(int,line.rstrip().split(","))# strip new line char and add each list to the dict, ind will increment line by line
print(list_dict)
{'list1': [-1, 2, 1], 'list2': [0, 4, 4, 1]}
```

You should look at the docs for [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: i guess OP wants the list element as `int`, and why do you make a dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

I think so you need search more before ask in **Stackoverflow** but you can try it.

```
file = open("text.txt")
#Now I get all lines from file via readlines(return list)
#After i use map and lambda to go each line and split by ',' and return new result
result_list_per_line = map(lambda line: line.split(','), file.readlines())

print result_list_per_lines #Ex: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```